# How to get value from selected input field (not using id)

Tags: javascript, input

I try to do simple code for guessing notes by ear. I have tabs with several empty input fields and you need to put right numbers in these fields according to certain melody (for guitar fretboard)  . One button shows first note, another button checks whether you put right or wrong number and depend on it approves or erase your number.

I know how to check every input field using its id's but can i do it such way that when i push 2nd button it get value from **selected** input and compare it to its placeholder or value attribute?

It is my codepen 
https://codepen.io/fukenist/pen/BxJRwW
Script part

```
     function showfirst() {
 document.getElementById("fst").value = "12" 
}
  function show1other() {
    var snote = document.getElementById("scnd").value;
    if (snote == 9 ){
      document.getElementById("scnd").value = "9";
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById("scnd").value = "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Being an amateur guitarist myself, I find this question very interesting. However, as it stands, it is difficult to understand exactly what you are trying to do (Even being a guitarist myself) can you try rephrasing your question to make it clearer?

Comment: I want to fill all inputs one by one and check it immediately using 2nd button - for example 2nd note 9 and if i will put number 5 and push button - number will dissapear - if i will put 9 and push - it will stay in field. Now i can do it using id selector for each input different so i need as much functions as inputs i have (or in worse scenari as many buttons) 
In ideal scenario i need only one button(function) for checking correctness number
I hope it help, if not give me more try to explain.) Thanks!

Comment: https://codepen.io/fukenist/pen/BxJRwW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all your inputs and loop over them.

**Sample:**

```js
// Get all inputs as an array (actually NodeList, to be precise; but it behaves similar to an array for this use case)
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

// Function to reveal the first input's value
function showFirst(){
  inputs[0].value = inputs[0].dataset.v;
}

// Function to check all values and clear input if wrong
function checkAll(){
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    if(input.dataset.v !== input.value){
      // Wrong answer, clear input
      input.value = '';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input data-v="12" size="2" value=""/>
<input data-v="9" size="2" value=""/>
<input data-v="8" size="2" value=""/>
<br/>
<button onclick="showFirst()">Show First</button>
<button onclick="checkAll()">Check All</button>
```

**Notes:**

1. I have used `data-v` to store the correct answer instead of `placeholder` as that attribute has a semantically different meaning
2. It may be out of turn but my two cents: Writing out entire songs like this by hand may become tedious. Consider using a JSON string or something similar to map out the tabs and use a templating framework to align them.. Some things you may need to look out for while designing something like this : Alignment of notes (successive notes, simultaneous notes), timing of the song, special moves like slide, hammer on etc.
3. It may be a better idea to make the Guitar Strings be a background element (either as a background-image or as absolutely positioned overlapping divs) (so You don't have to worry about the lines going out of alignment)

**Reference:**

[HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

[`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is great way, i'm enjoyed by result!